# Displaying Flask WTForms fields horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

My Flask web app uses WTForms to display a form with two `SelectFields`. The form is a custom form which inherits from WTForms `form.Form` class. I also have a BaseView which is imported from Flask-Admin. The user input consists of several `SelectField`s (from `wtforms.fields`) and they are all stacked vertically on top of one another. Is there a way to display the SelectFields horizontally so that `field1` is to the left of `field2`, instead of above `field2`?  Thanks.

Current code (edited for clarity):

```
# form.py

from flask_admin import BaseView
from wtforms import form
from wtforms.fields import SelectField

class FormA(form.Form):
    field1 = SelectField(choices=[('A', 'Choice A'), ('B', 'Choice B')])
    field2 = SelectField(choices=[('C', 'Choice C'), ('D', 'Choice D')])
   
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ViewA(BaseView):
    @expose('/', methods=('GET',))
    def index(self):
        form = FormA()
        return self.render('admin/form.html', form=form)
```

Here in the `form.html` file I'm importing flask-admin and creating the form:

```
<!--form.html-->

{% import "admin/lib.html" as lib with context %}

{% block head_tail %}
<!--other stuff-->
{% endblock %}

{% block subheader %} {
<form method="GET">
    {{ lib.render_form_fields(form)}}
</form>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<!--other stuff-->
{% endblock %}


{% block tail %}
<!--other stuff-->
{% endblock %}
```

Right now `field1` and `field2` are stacked vertically but I would like them to be displayed side-by-side. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could target the form using css and set `display: flex`.

You could give your form an id:

```
<form id="myform" method="GET">
    {{ lib.render_form_fields(form)}}
</form>
```

and target it using css like this:

```
#myform {
    display: flex;
}
```

---

Alternatively if you don't want the entire form to have `display` set to `flex` you could surround `render_form_fields` with a div and set `display: flex` on this div.